# Web scrape website with dropdown menu that changes website dynamically (onchange)

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

So I'm trying to scrape census data from a website that changes dynamically when a county is selected from the drop down menu. It looks like this:

```
<select id="cat_id_select_GEO" onchange="changeHeaderSelection('GEO');
<option value="0500000US01001" select="selected">Autaga County, Alabama</option>
<select>
```

[a link](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk)

So from the research i've done, it sounds like i need to make some sort of Get request? (selenium?) but I am completely lost on how to do this. I know how to get the data i want, once i've made the county selection. But I've never had to scrape something where the website changes dynamically (i.e. the url doesn't change)

I understand that some may find this to be a simple question... but I've read numerous other similar questions and would greatly benefit from someone walking me through example, and/or directing me to a solid guide.

this is what i've been messing around with so far. I can see it kinda works at selecting the values... but it spits out this error: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)

```
    for index, row in StateURLs.iterrows():
        url = row['URL']
        state = row['STATE']

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url)
        select_county = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cat_id_select_GEO'))
        options = select_county.options
        for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
            select_county.select_by_index(index)
```

I also would love help on how to then convert this webpages to beautiful soup so i can scrape each page after the selection is made

Comment: Perhaps it is my location but that url still redirect to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

The main landing page does get requests with a query string that returns a json string containing the info from that is first returned when you submit your query including further urls that are listed on the results page.

```
import requests
search_term = 'searchTerm: Autauga County, Alabama'
search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+')
r = requests.get('https://factfinder.census.gov/rest/communityFactsNav/nav?N=0&_t=1558559559868&log=t&searchTerm=term ' + search_term + ',Alabama&src=').json()
```

Here is an example of that [json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5d99fc364d404c8e868edbb690be2c31)

I can generate the correct url to use in the browser which returns all that data as json but can't seem to configure requests so works. Perhaps someone else can pick up this and work it out. I will look again tomorrow.

```
r = requests.get('https://factfinder.census.gov/rest/communityFactsNav/nav?N=0&_t=1558559559868&log=t&searchTerm=term ' + search_term + ',Alabama&src=', allow_redirects= True).json()
url = 'https://factfinder.census.gov' + r['CFMetaData']['measuresAndLinks']['links']['2017 American Community Survey'][0]['url']
code = url.split('/')[-2]
url = 'https://factfinder.census.gov/tablerestful/tableServices/renderProductData?renderForMap=f&renderForChart=f&pid=ACS_17_5YR_{}&prodToReplace=ACS_16_5YR_{}&log=t&_ts=576607332612'.format(code, code)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, so with this method i wouldn't have to use selenium? One of the main reasons i was planning on using selenium was because I also want to click the arrow to display the most recent data from 2017.

Comment: It depends as I can't view the link you have posted. I have followed the instructions where it sends me to a landing page. Then looked at the activity from there. The json response from what I show gives the link to 2017 American Community Survey results. You would need to see if that link in turn yields data via requests you can use i.e. doing a subsequent get request.

Comment: Table data can be regex'd to produce a json string from get request to https://factfinder.census.gov/tablerestful/tableServices/renderProductData?renderForMap=f&renderForChart=f&src=CF&log=t&_ts=576606243205

Comment: For example the json yields this url for 2017 data: https://factfinder.census.gov/fbkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/17_5YR/DP05/0500000US06071  which in browser re-directs to: https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=CF

Comment: Ive only used json requests once, so i'm pretty unfamiliar with it, but from the example you sent, i'm not sure how to use that, as it doesn't look like it contains the tabular data on the normal website. Edit: maybe you could direct me to some help on how to use json